# Add global string to checkedlistbox?

Tags: c#, global-variables, checkedlistbox

I'm trying to make a to do list using a checkedlistbox, by using a secondary form to set a global string and add that to my checkedlistbox. Problem is it's not working.
Heres the code for the add button on my form1 which opens up a secondary form where i set my global string:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.ShowDialog();
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(global.Items);
        }
```

Note: global.Items is the global string which i want to add.
i dont mind not using a global string, any way to do this is appreciated.
thanks in advance

Heres the class where i set Items:

```
 class global
    {
        public static string Items= "";
    }
```

And just incase heres the Form2 code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    global.Items = textBox1.Text;
    this.Hide();
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    f1.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: is `global.Items` part of form2..? if so show it's structure please show all relevant code as well as all variables and how they are initialized and or declared.

Comment: This is not enough for us to go on. Can you show us more code? Preferably where global.Items is set.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the global variable `global.Items`, you're just retrieving its value. If you wanted to use the variable instead, parameter would have to be defined as `out` or `ref`, which isn't the case of `Items.Add()`.

What happens is, that the value of `global.Items` is passed to `Items.Add()` in the moment when the call is made, but future modifications of `global.Items` don't affect the item.